# datagridview: add new entries at the top

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Is it possible to add new entries in a datagridview at the top instead at the bottom?

Comment: You mean other than changing the sort order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by sorting the rows by an ID.

Answer (score 11):

The DataGridView binds to your source collection, so if you insert them at the top they should show up at the top. Try adding new items by inserting them:

```
list.Insert(0, item)
```

Comment: your answer is obviously the best, I think it was simply not clear what you meant.

Answer (score 5):

This way worked for me:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, new string[] {
    "Data1", "Data2", "Data3" // [, "DataN"] ..
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with the sorting, you have to deal with Keys then. Simply do what jjrdk had mentioned and use the built in functionality of the insert(rowIndex,rowObject) method like such:

```
'First create a new row
Dim tmpRow = New DataGridViewRow

'Dimension or do whatever
tmpRow.Height = _cellRectSize

'Add the row to your DataGridView(i.e dgvEditor) at index 0 for it to be at top
Me.dgvEditor.Rows.Insert(0, tmpRow)
```

Have used this exact code in a few projects and it works just fine. Hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 0):

You can also insert in the middle.  This will give you 1,2,3,4,5,6 in order.

```
        dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, new string[] { "6", "6", "6" });
        dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, new string[] { "5", "5", "5" });
        dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, new string[] { "4", "4", "4" });

        dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, new string[] { "1", "1", "1" });
        dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(1, new string[] { "2", "2", "2" });
        dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(2, new string[] { "3", "3", "3" });
```